# How to run Tizen Certificate Manager from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019, tizen

I use Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.6 with Visual Studio Tools for Tizen (3.1.0.0).
Tizen projects can be built and run on a Tizen Emulator but when I try to open Tizen Certificate Manager from **Tools > Tizen > Tizen Certificate Manager** it doesn't open anything. The only thing I see when Visual Studio runs without administrator rights is a window to allow certificate-manager.exe to make changes on device.

How to run the Tizen Certificate Manager properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to open the Tizen Certificate Manager manually.
Go to a directory with Tizen SDK and run "eclipse.exe"
The full path can be like this: "C:\Tizen SDK\tools\certificate-manager\eclipse.exe"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and this was the solution:

Install TizenSDK folder in path without blank spaces. (or modify .bat script)

I had installed it in path C:/Program Files/Tizen/SDK and Visual Studio 2019 run script from %tizenSDKpath%\tools\certificate-manager\CertificateManager.bat which returned error path C:/Program not found.

I reinstalled TizenSDK on different path C:/TizenSDK and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, plz, check new UPDATE of Tizen-SDK via Tools > Tizen > Tizen Package Manager
Recommend to use latest SDK environment.

Comment: I've just installed it. No updates available for now.

Comment: Go to Tool - Option - Tizen - Tools, could you check all green? If not, need to specify correct path.

Comment: All checks are green. I even deployed and debugged on my watch from Visual Studio. It seems only problem with calling Tizen Certificate Manager from Visual Studio directly.

Answer (score 0):

I run from Path-to-tizen-sdk\TizenSDK\tools\certificate-manager\certificate-manager.exe